# I want to become a French citizen as my father was born in France to American parents on French soil

Tags: france, citizenship, dual-citizenship

My deceased father was born in France while my grandfather was stationed in Germany for the United States Air Force. My grandmother was shopping and went into labor in France and my father was born in France.  Does this allow for me to apply for French citizenship?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this has absolutely no relevance under French law. Being born in France on a visit doesn't open any specific path to French citizenship. Unlike many countries in the Americas, France only knows two restricted forms of *Jus soli*:

- The “*double droit du sol*” (or double *jus soli*): if you are born in France to a parent who was also born in France (including French colonies), you are French from birth (and your children are therefore French).
- If you are born in France and grow up in France (technically: reside in France when you turn 18 and have spent at least 5 years in France between 11 and 18), you become French as of right when you turn 18 (and you can apply earlier too).

Neither of these seem to apply to your father. Since he was never French, there is no point going into the intricacies of whether he would have transmitted his citizenship to you.

Obviously, you may still apply for naturlization like anybody else but there are many requirements (residence in France for a number of years, speaking French, etc.)